# Alinear elementos verticalmente

Tags: html, css

Lo que quiero es que los input que hay en la parte derecha no estén unos más a la izquierda o a la derecha que otros. No me importa si es necesario usar css o si simplemente es una tag del div.

```html
<div name="dinero">
   <div name="monedas">
    <label>Monedas de 1 cent: </label>
    <input id="1" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 2 cents: </label>
    <input id="2" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 5 cents: </label>
    <input id="5" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 10 cents: </label>
    <input id="10" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 20 cents: </label>
    <input id="20" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 50 cents: </label>
    <input id="50" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 1 euro: </label>
    <input id="100" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 2 euros: </label>
    <input id="200" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 30 euros: </label>
    <input id="3000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
   </div>
   <div id="billetes">
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 5 euros: </label>
    <input id="500" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 10 euros: </label>
    <input id="1000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 20 euros: </label>
    <input id="2000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 50 euros: </label>
    <input id="5000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 100 euros: </label>
    <input id="10000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 200 euros: </label>
    <input id="20000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hola hugo has tratado de trabajar con bootstrap o materialize???

Comment: @ger, justo iba a decir lo mismo. Hugo Galingo Lorenzo, existen bastantes frameworks y librerías que puedes aplicar a este problema que tienes.

Comment: sinceramente no, pero quiero una solución simple y sencilla. Sin complicarme mucho.

Comment: @HugoGalindoLorenzo precisamente bootstrap es simple o sencilla :D XD

Comment: ok, pues como se usa :)             ya he dicho que hace mucho (años) que no programo (solo me acuerdo de lo básico de javascript y html)

Comment: volviendo a ver el codigo tambien puedes usar una tabla html

Comment: Si quieres sin librerías la única manera sería que le apliques un margin pero con distintos valores a cada input, o sino puedes poner ese input debajo del label y allí estará alienado, o tambien ponerle un witdth al label.

Comment: gracias ger por tu comentario, voy a probar lo que me has dicho, a ver si funciona :9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es una de las posibles soluciones que mencioné con el tag [table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) de html

```html
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Monedas de 1 cent: </label></td>
                <td><input id="1" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Monedas de 2 cents: </label></td>
                <td><input id="2" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()"><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Monedas de 5 cents: </label>  </td>
               <td> <input id="5" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()"></td>
            </tr>
<!-- el resto de tu codigo -->
        </table>
```

Comment: he terminado el código antes que tú ^-^   Pero por supuesto te marco como correcta la respuesta ya que la idea ha sido tuya. :)

Comment: @ger, te llevaste el premio (y).

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal : "> creo que es mejor las cosas mas sencillas.. ; ">

Comment: @ger, efectivamente.

Comment: Esta respuesta es realmente una mala idea, las tablas **NO** fueron diseñadas para generar layouts o para dar estilo, va en contra de las buenas prácticas de HTML.

Comment: @Shaz, no tenia idea de esa mala práctica, tendré cuidado (y).

Comment: Las tablas de HTML existen para tabular información, no para dar estilo, al pretender «dar estilo» o generar la estructura con tablas, se está dañando toda la semántica del sitio, se complica a futuro las mejoras del mismo, no va a funcionar bien en todos los dispositivos y por último y tal vez lo más importante, se está afectando la accesibilidad (personas con discapacidad). Esto no es nuevo, es una mala práctica desde hace ya varios años, desde la década pasada.

Answer (score 4):

**La respuesta aceptada es una mala práctica y una pésima aplicación de las tablas HTML, y no debe ser aplicada en ningún contexto.** Aquí la sustentación:

Las tablas de HTML existen para tabular información, no para dar estilo, al pretender «dar estilo» o generar la estructura con tablas, se está dañando toda la semántica del sitio, se complica a futuro las mejoras del mismo, no va a funcionar bien en todos los dispositivos y por último y tal vez lo más importante, se está afectando la accesibilidad (personas con discapacidad). Esto no es nuevo, es una mala práctica desde hace ya varios años, desde la década pasada.

---

Mi respuesta/solución:

En cuanto a si debes utilizar CSS o no, la respuesta es: **Sí, debes usar CSS**, HTML no ofrece estilos, y en el fondo cuando no utilizas estilos, los resulta asignando el navegador (estilos predeterminados).

Teniendo en cuenta que dices que no deseas utilizar ningún framework, lo más sencillo podría ser hacer que `<label>` sea un elemento `inline-block` y asignarle un ancho fijo. El único «problema» sería el responsive, para lo cual tendrías que aplicar media queries.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div name="dinero">
   <div name="monedas">
    <label>Monedas de 1 cent: </label>
    <input id="1" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 2 cents: </label>
    <input id="2" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 5 cents: </label>
    <input id="5" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 10 cents: </label>
    <input id="10" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 20 cents: </label>
    <input id="20" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 50 cents: </label>
    <input id="50" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br> 
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 1 euro: </label>
    <input id="100" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 2 euros: </label>
    <input id="200" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Monedas de 30 euros: </label>
    <input id="3000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
   </div>
   <div id="billetes">
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 5 euros: </label>
    <input id="500" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 10 euros: </label>
    <input id="1000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 20 euros: </label>
    <input id="2000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 50 euros: </label>
    <input id="5000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 100 euros: </label>
    <input id="10000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
     <br>
    <label>Billetes de 200 euros: </label>
    <input id="20000" type="number" min="0" value="0" onchange="sumar()">
     <br>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: justo pusiste mi solución XD

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal tardé algunos minutos redactándola, así que técnicamente no es tu solución, de hecho tampoco es mía, es de todos.

Comment: bueno, entonces la solución de todos :D